# On the origins of Homological algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, math-history

In Martin Krieger's book "Doing Mathematics: Convention Subject, Calculation, Analogy" (2003) I find the following statement (apparently, a quote from somone else) : "Homological algebra starts from the regrettable fact that not all modules are projective". And then he adds "Those regrettable facts, the breaks or failures of exactness, are measured by the nonzero homology group".

Could anyone shed some light on those sentences? Any insights into the origins and history of homological algebra?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how to understand this sentence. It is certainly possible to do homological algebra over a field, and every "module" (vector space) over a field is projective. Maybe the author is thinking about derived functors like Ext and Tor, where it does matter that something is not projective? I don't know enough about the history of homological algebra to know if this is the start of it.

Comment: Related: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf

Comment: For what it's worth, the quote is apparently from the book *The Selected Works of J. Frank Adams, Volume 1*, by Adams, May, Thomas (more specifically, in the part "Algebraic Topology in the last decade").

Comment: Yes, the wuote is from Adams. Krieger mentions it. I am interested in a comment on the quote though.